# How can I enable copy-and-paste in my JavaScript-based Universal Windows app?

Tags: javascript, clipboard, windows-10-universal

I have the following in my `index.html`:

```
<div>Hello!</div>
```

When I run my app, the text "Hello!" appears, but I can't highlight it or copy it. Is there a way to enable this behaviour for my app?

Comment: add `contenteditable="true"` to div like this: `<div contenteditable="true">Hello!</div>`.

Comment: Does not let me highlight nor copy text.